# Save/restore desktop session

Tags: debian, session

My Linux session got saved somehow and every time I restart, it's restoring the same saved session (a terminal and a particular program).

I am not able to find the setting or the saved file to disable this.

I even installed gconf-editor and enabled the option to save my session, hoping it would overwrite whatever the old settings are, but it's not working.

Comment: It depends on which desktop are you using. If you are not in gnome, gconf-editor is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is Gnome we are talking about, then the saved session file might be in  `~/.config/gnome-session/saved-session/`

Check it out and rename the folder for testing purposes instead of deleting...

Comment: It did not work. I even deleted that folder. Is there some system log where we can read what might be loading this ?

Comment: I don't think it logs that thoroughly. You can also look into `~/.config/autostart` if the autostarted apps aren't there. But do not delete the directory as a whole...

Comment: Thank you ! It was the autostart. After removing those files, the problem is solved !!